# order results by most searched in solr index

Tags: search, autocomplete, solr, indexing

I'm using Solr to implement a predictive search (with autocomplete) on a website, and I want to filter the results by mostly searched in the index. 
I mean, as the words are searched I want to keep a record of the search so I can show the results ordered by relevancy.

thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have an index of search terms entered.  This can be built by mining your search logs.  The relevancy of these search terms is dependent on their frequency.  This relevancy factor can be an [external field](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Solr+Field+Types#SolrFieldTypes-WorkingwithExternalFiles) (so that you dont have to reindex it periodically).  Periodically, this external file is updated with the frequency factor.

Auto complete field is fed from this "previous search terms index", sorted by relevancy score that depends on the external field.

Another thing to consider is - auto complete terms can be built from your actual document index itself.  So, you may add to your auto complete field, results from the "previous search terms index" and "original document index".  (For instance, what if the term is in your index, but was never previously searched? )

Comment: thank you in advance!! what do you mean with "This can be built by mining your search logs"??

Comment: You wanted - " to filter the results by mostly searched in the index". To know this, the search terms need to be logged - either in webserver's logs where search term is part of query parameter - or by the client web application logging them to a file/database.  Once they are logged, they can be indexed as previous search terms.  The frequency of these search terms will change over time, and can be fed as an external field.  HTH.

Comment: thanks!! do you know how to generate the request log, and fill it with each request sent from the client?? 
thank you again!!

Comment: How are you searching solr?  Using solrj?